# How to remove values from url using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a url as below

```
https://example.com/#registration-update?gigya=true&socialProvider=yahoo&gigyaUID=_guid_59DUvJro84GQM2B_o-SjcoWyforCmmvGQYVdMX1yhtlYImE_62mKDUWiUtPo0cxp&lastName=Jackson&firstName=peter&email=peter2015@ymail.com&zip=
```

i take the values from the url and populate in form on form submit i should clear the values and make the url as `https://example.com/`

How to do this using jquery please help

to fetch the values i have used the jquery as below.

```
var username = getUrlVars()["firstName"];
    var lastname = getUrlVars()["lastName"];
    var email = getUrlVars()["email"];
    var zipcode = getUrlVars()["zip"];

    $('#regi_firstname').val(username); 
    $('#regi_lastname').val(lastname);  
    $('#regi_user_email').val(email);   
    $('#regi_confirmemail').val(email); 
    $('#zip').val(zipcode);

 function getUrlVars() {
        var vars = [], hash;
        var hashes = window.location.href.slice(window.location.href.indexOf('?') + 1).split('&');
        for (var i = 0; i < hashes.length; i++) {
            hash = hashes[i].split('=');
            vars.push(hash[0]);
            vars[hash[0]] = hash[1];
        }
        return vars;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I wouuld think you would be able to use substring(0,19) to just take the first nineteen characters or use var newurl = url.split(".com/) and then take newurl[0] should only have first part

Answer (score 0):

You could do it like this, but it is not a very solid solution..

```
var url = 'https://example.com/#registration-update?gigya=true&socialProvider=yahoo&gigyaUID=_guid_59DUvJro84GQM2B_o-SjcoWyforCmmvGQYVdMX1yhtlYImE_62mKDUWiUtPo0cxp&lastName=Jackson&firstName=peter&email=peter2015@ymail.com&zip=';

var urlCut = url.split('/').slice(3).join('/');
var urlBase = url.replace(urlCut, "");
alert(urlBase);
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/uSGkM/)

Answer (score 0):

You actually don't need jQuery but use good old javascript regex to find the matching URL. The solution below will work even if the domain name changes ;).

For example:

```
var url = 'https://example.com/#registration-update?gigya=true&socialProvider=yahoo&gigyaUID=_guid_59DUvJro84GQM2B_o-SjcoWyforCmmvGQYVdMX1yhtlYImE_62mKDUWiUtPo0cxp&lastName=Jackson&firstName=peter&email=peter2015@ymail.com&zip=';

var matches = url.match("htt(p|ps):(\/\/|\/\/www.)[a-z]+.[a-z]{3}");
alert(matches[0]);
```

Answer (score 0):

You may be interested in `purl`, a JS utility for parsing URLs and extracting information from them. [Here](https://github.com/allmarkedup/purl) is the Github repo where you can find it and its documentation. [Here](https://github.com/allmarkedup/purl/archive/v2.3.1.zip) is the download link (v2.3.1). Transforming your code to use the library:

```
$('#regi_firstname').val($.url("firstName")); 
$('#regi_lastname').val($.url("lastName"));  
$('#regi_user_email').val($.url("email"));   
$('#regi_confirmemail').val($.url("email")); 
$('#zip').val($.url("zip"));
```

To get the base url of the current location, use:

```
$.url().attr('protocol') + $.url().attr('host')
```